# how to replace "\r\n" to < br > python pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

[Report-1.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4zqp.png)
[AssertFail.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj6fj.png)
I tried to import data from csv to html. how to replace "\r\n" to < br >
want to write line in html

```
< br >** Assertion failure! **< br >
< br >Message: ""Expected AO1 Step High delay: 0.025 ms. Actual Step High delay: 0.03500009ms.""
< br >
< br >Expected: A value less than 0.025< br >
< br >Actual:   0.03500009 at : 0.0< br >
```

python code:

```
file_name='AssertFail.csv'
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'\\Desktop\\Result\\MR\\')
AssertFail=pd.read_csv(path+file_name)
AssertFail.drop_duplicates("Test_Case_Name",inplace=True)
df5= pd.DataFrame(AssertFail)
df5['Failed_Assert_Message'].replace("\r\n",'<br>',inplace=True)
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'\\Desktop\\Result\\Report\\')
df5.to_html(path +'Report-1.html',escape=True)
```

its not working. Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing regex = True

Try changing this line from this:

```
df5['Failed_Assert_Message'].replace("\r\n",'<br>',inplace=True)
```

to this:

```
df5['Failed_Assert_Message'].replace("\r\n",'<br>',inplace=True, regex = True)
```

Comment: Thank you @BrutalPeanut [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11575482/brutalpeanut)  "regex=True" is working.